# RXJS observable not completing on flatMap(Observable::from)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rxjs, rxjs5

What I'm trying to do is pull some data from mongodb using streams, do some operations on data, use keys of incoming data to do another query in mongo and then join the data.

The actual code is much more complex but i will illustrate with simpler example.

The problem I have is that on complete never gets fired and I'm assuming because the outer observable never completes.

```
const o$ = RxNode.fromStream(getDataFromMongo(), 'end'))
    .filter(doSomeFiltering)
    .bufferCount(100)
    .flatMap(bufferedData => {
        let ids = _.map(bufferedData, 'id');

        return RxNode.fromStream(getMoreDataFromMongodb(ids))
            .reduce(createMapIdObject(), {})
            .flatMap(createdMap => {  //because i get here, outer never complets
                return Observable.from(bufferedData)
                .map(item => ({
                    id: item.id,
                    size: createdMap[item.id].size
                }));
            });
    })
    .subscribe(
        c => console.log(c),
        err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log('COMPLETE') // never happens
    );
```

**How can i get the complete to fire? Or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to achieve?**

If I chain `.finally(() => console.log(done)`  on `Observable.from` inside nested `flatMap`, that gets fired. So inner observable is completing but outer doesn't.

Comment: Some observables do not ever emit a complete notification. Why can you not do what you want to do in the success function

Comment: Not sure I understand what do you mean to do it in success function. When i get to success function i only have one set of data and i need both to combine them.

Comment: Can you wrap the whole thing in an observable?

Comment: how getDataFromMongo looks like?

Comment: It's a stream: `db.coll.find({some: conditions}, {some: fields}).stream();`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add `take(1)`just before you subscribe.